# CSS Background rectangle width won't extend to full device width

Tags: css, rectangles

I am trying to make a homepage for my portfolio website with a responsive css background rectangle and a side-by-side hero with text on the left and an image on the right, such as the website template [here](https://zyro.com/preview/dovile?utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=aff1635&utm_campaign=aff35&transaction_id=1024f3e0a19650f753621b3537acae). I can't figure out what I did wrong in my HTML or CSS that's making it so that the background css rectangle isn't extending the full width of the screen. I'm new at this, so I would appreciate the help.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@500&display=swap');

/*Variable*/

:root {
  --primary-color: #0d081a;
  --secondary-blue: #eaf0f9;
  --secondary-gray: #48463b;
  --body-bg: ffffff;
}


/*Global Styles*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--body-bg);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.background {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: max-content;
  background-color: var(--secondary-blue);
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.primary-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding: 0.6em 1.6em;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 2rem;
}


/*nav*/

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50px;
  height: auto;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
}


/*hero section*/

#hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10rem;
}

#hero .container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#hero .container .left {
  flex: 6;
}

#hero .container .right {
  flex: 8;
}

#hero .left .subheading {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

#hero .left .heading {
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#hero .left .desc {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  max-width: 400px;
  font-size: 1.5 rem;
  color: var(--secondary-blue);
}

#hero .right {
  text-align: right;
}

#hero .right img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
  height: 600px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 30%;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 9px;
  }
  #hero .container {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  #hero .container .right {
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  #hero .container .left {
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 0;
    flex: 1;
    height: fit-content;
  }
  #hero .left .buttons {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #hero .left .heading {
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #hero .container .left .desc {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  #hero .right img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #hero .container .right {
    flex: 6;
  }
}


/* End Hero Section*/


/*Navbar*/

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.logo a,
.main-nav a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.main-nav a {
  color: #34495e;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
  color: #718daa;
}

.header {
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}


/* Nav Media Queries*/

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .header,
  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
  }
  .header {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    .header {
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 1150px;
    }
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .header {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--nav section-->
  <header class="nav">
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <!--end nav section-->


  <!--hero section-->
  <section id="hero">
    <div class="background">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
          <p class="subheading"></p>
          <h2 class="heading">
            <div class="wrapper"><span>Hello, nice </span></div>
            <div class="wrapper"><span>to"meet" you!</span></div>
          </h2>
          <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <div class="buttons">
            <a href="#" class="primary-btn">Contact Me</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <img src="/linkedinheadshot.png" alt="picture">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--End hero section-->
</body>
```

I've tried adjusting the padding and margins and the widths in the @mediaquery. Researching solutions on google and stack overflow.

Comment: If, by background, you mean the div with class '.background' then it does not extend full width because you've set the width to max-content. Change this to width: 100% and it will fill the width of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

i review your problem and if you use

```
#hero {
  min-width: 100vw;
  display: block;
  background-color: var(--secondary-blue);
}
html #hero .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; 
}
```

it will solve you problem
i am also a new web developer and learning now javascript
if it help you like this if you had still any problem post your question